# Documents with same Raven-Entity-Name not grouped into collection

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I've got this weird situtation with `Ravendb` collections.

Saved two documents with exactly the same metadata:

Documents:

```
{
    "Title": "Some title",
    "ProductType": "Some type",
    "Description": "Some description",
    "Keywords": "Some keywords"
}
```

Metadata:

```
{
    "Raven-Entity-Name": "MetaDatas",
    "Raven-Clr-Type": "DomainModel.MetaData, DomainModel"
}
```

The `ravendb studio` won't show them into one collection and loading/querying the documents via `C#` code gives me always `null` as result:

```
var metaData = Session.Query<MetaData>().SingleOrDefault(m => m.ProductType == productType);
```

and

```
var metaData = Session.Load<MetaData>("MetaDatas-1");
```

Comment: See my update, hope that answers your question

Comment: I also tried to reset the index, but that didn't help either.

Comment: After a server reboot the problem doesn't exist anymore. Deleted the old documents and now everything is working as it should. Any idea what could be the reason?